# What is my approximate body fat percentage and at what speed should I cut? (with pics)

Tags: body-fat, cutting

Here are my recent pics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D0PV.jpg

I used an online calculator and it said that I have ~21% body fat. Does that sound okay? Or do I have more?

Also,  I have cut from 89Kg (196lbs) to 70Kg (154lbs) in the last 1 year. I'm so tired of cutting but I guess, I need to loose 8-9 kilos more to get below 15% to bulk. So at what rate should I aim to loose my fat? Also, any other suggestions?

Comment: For what reason do you want to further reduce bodyweight? For appearance, bodybuilding competition, making a weight class for a sport, or general health?

Comment: @DavidScarlett he just means general health. And OP, you should cut more. There's no point in bulking if you already look fat.

Comment: First, don't rely on online calculators to gauge any type of fitness level.  At best, it's a guess.  Second, to successfully lose body fat, you must make sure to train and eat optimally.

Answer (score 2):

You can give Jeff Nippard’s podcast on dieting a go (https://open.spotify.com/episode/5iuWZvuKxOTL8Vlxk6oOyB?si=rLJiG5K2T0KeRgDiNvt7Xg).

From what I gather, there is no hard and fast rule. You need to experiment as you diet as each individual adapt differently. The person he spoke to in the video recommends to start with 1% of your body weight and adjust from there.

If you find you’re losing motivation, find other ways and don’t be too hooked up with the numbers. After all, we are all working towards a healthier body and it should be enjoyable! Sustainable fat loss is better. All the best